# Can not access functions between modules bundled into the same Browserify bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundle, browserify

**PREFACE**: I have read several SO posts about trying to access code in a Browserify bundle from code that is *not* in the bundle.  I am **not** trying to do that.  I am having trouble accessing code *between* modules that were bundled together into the same bundle.

I bundled two Javascript files in my Node.JS v.8.11.1 project into one *standalone* bundle using Browserify:

```
browserify solidity-helpers-misc.js create-game-page-support.js --standalone browserified  > bundle.js
```

Unfortunately, code sourced from the *create-game-page-support.js* file cannot access code from the *solidity-helpers-misc.js* file.  Any such references are **undefined**.  I checked the `browserified` namespace in the Chrome debugger and it is defined, but just with the basic set of Javascript Object functions like: toString(), etc. and nothing else.

For example, this code is in *bundle.js*, sourced from the *solidity-helpers-misc.js* file:

```
function getNonceViaUuid(){
    return uuidv4();
}

// Yes.  Export the code so it works with require().
module.exports =
    {
        getNonceViaUuid: getNonceViaUuid,
    };


}).call(this,require('_process'),"/../../../common/solidity-helpers-misc.js","/../../../common")
```

However, when I try to access the *getNonceViaUuid()* function from this code in *bundle.js* that was sourced from *create-game-page-support.js* as shown in this code snippet:

```
$('#create-game-btn').click(
    function(e)
    {
        console.log("Testing access to browserified file.  Remember to add sourcemap later.");

        var nonce = getNonceViaUuid();
        ...
```

The debugger pauses with an exception complaining that **getNonceViaUuid** is *undefined*.  As I said, I inspected the *browserified* namespaces in the debugger and it does not have **getNonceViaUuid** attached to it.

Note, the first file *solidity-helpers-misc.js* is a server side file that uses *require()* statements.  The second file *create-game-page-support.js* is a client side code module that I want to have access to the first file, but on the client side.  That is why I am trying to use Browserify, so I can use the code in the first file both on the server and on the client.

How can I access functions across modules that were bundled together in the same Browserify bundle?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not requiring the server side module *solidity-helpers-misc.js* module from within the client side *module create-game-page-support.js*.  By adding the following to the top of my client side module:

```
var solidty_helpers_misc = require('../../../common/solidity-helpers-misc');
```

And then prefixing the **getNonceViaUuid()** call with that module:

```
ar nonce = solidty_helpers_misc.getNonceViaUuid();
```

Then it worked.  Looking back, the "alien" feeling of using *require()* on the client side is what tripped me up at first.